# Using System.Diagnostic.Process.Start and assigning parameters in outside .exe file

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new at C# development and I'm trying to figure out how I can use an outside application to accept parameters set in my VS (2008) project. The idea is to have the outside application accept coordinates to rotate the screen. So have it rotate to 90 degrees, 180 degrees, and 270 degrees. So I have two buttons. One to send the command to rotate and the other to reset the values. I was thinking it would be easier to just use a list box and have the three options and use a switch statement to execute each option. The only thing I'm unsure of is how to have System.Diagnostic.Process.Start execute the rotate.exe and pass the parameters I'm setting for each rotate option. Any ideas?... I couldn't find anything that covered this exactly, but if you find anything of reference that may be helpful, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Process.Start can start with arguments.

Sample

```
Process.Start("rotate.exe", "90");
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or use ProcessStartInfo.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "rotate.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "90";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at what options Process class offers.  Take a look at [a this] (http://www.dotnetperls.com/process).

```
 static void OpenMicrosoftWord(string f)
{
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
startInfo.Arguments = f;
Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```